# How to use more than one table with OUTPUT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to insert columns of different tables in the OUTPUT clause of an INSERT statement, such as:

```
DECLARE @insertedrecords TABLE (Id int, [Guid] uniqueidentifier);

INSERT INTO mytable 
    (column names here...)
OUTPUT inserted.id_no, b.[Guid] INTO @insertedrecords 
SELECT 
    column names here...
FROM @myTVP b
```

Currently, using the above I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "b.Guid" could not be bound.

Comment: You can use: OUTPUT inserted.id_no, inserted.[Guid] INTO @insertedrecords

Comment: Post the original query. It depends actually are you inserting  `b.[Guid]` into `mytable` table ?

Comment: @Prdp No. `b.Guid` is not being inserted in `mytable`.

Answer (score 0):

`Inserted` special table will hold the records those are inserted into the *Target* table not all the data from *Source* table. When a column from target table is not part of `Insert` list then in `OUTPUT` clause it will be `NULL`

So you need two different `Inserts`

```
DECLARE @insertedrecords TABLE (Id int, [Guid] uniqueidentifier);

INSERT INTO mytable 
    (column names here...)
SELECT 
    column names here...
FROM @myTVP b

Insert into @insertedrecords(Id,Guid)
select id_no, [Guid] 
From @myTVP
```